# How to change value of variable used in word document in C#

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I have used some variables in my word document. I have to print this word document in different scenarios and i am doing this in my C# application. Every time when i print this document i need to set the values of variables used the word document before printing.
I have used the following code. but it seems there is no affect.
Is there any proper solution for this issue ?

```
 string filepath = @"c:\Changesneed-Comments.docx"; ;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document doc = word.Documents.Add(filepath);

        doc.Variables["MTQProductName"].Value = "SamSung"; 

        doc.Fields.Update();

        doc.SaveAs2(@"c:\Changesneed-Comments34.docx");

        app.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is type of application in which you are using this code?

if it is asp.net website it will not work as expected, because word interop it is just wrapper library to support winword.exe where word is install. normally word is not installed on server.

however you can use [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) for your requirements in case of asp.net.

Comment: I am using it in window form application.